# How to get a certain layer parameters?

Tags: deep-learning, parameters, output, layer, transfer-learning

How can I get the values of the parameters of a certain layer in a transfer learning model? I need the parameters values not the output of the layer

Answer (score 0):

You can get the parameters of, for example, the *first layer* as follows:

```
print(model.layers[0].variables)
```

Output is something like this:

```
 [<tf.Variable 'simple_dense_7/kernel:0' shape=(1, 1) dtype=float32, numpy=array([[0.03688493]], dtype=float32)>,

<tf.Variable 'simple_dense_7/bias:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32, numpy=array([0.], dtype=float32)>]
```

The first one is the weight, the second is the bias.